# huge difference between RMSE and MAE in non-linear regressors

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, rms, mae

I am building non-linear regression models such as a Random Forest regressor , a KNN regressor or a SVM using a RBF kernel and I decided to use both RMSE and MAE as evaluation metrics.

I know that a big difference on the magnitude of RMSE and MAE is an indicator of the presence of outliers, at least in the case of linear regression as the fitted line gets pulled towards the outlying observations in order to minimise the error.

However how I can interpret a big difference between RMSE and MAE in non-linear models as the one that i mentioned above? Should they fit better outlying observations as they are non-linear?  What such a difference between the evaluation metrics can tell us for the non-linear models?